# Does Android store data on SQLite permanently or is it temporary storage?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

It seems like SQLite (1-st impression) stores it`s data temporary, while executing SQLiteOpenHelper and creating tables there, and inserting rows within onCreate method. 
The Q is: Is there an ability to store data permanently and do not create DB and Tables every time the app is start-up? As I understand the data kills, when user exit the app?
Sorry for my English and a lame question - I'm new to Android =)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, Your answers were very helpful

Comment: In addition I have the issued answer - can I write the data into tables bypassing oncreate method, I meen not row by row? Because when U have a large data this is inconvinient to create tables this way. May be there is an ability to insert data from SQLite tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial impression is incorrect. SQLite tables are persistent in Android - they exist as files in a particular directory based on your application's package id.

The idea of the SQLiteOpenHelper is to encapsulate database creation AND database upgrade in one place, so that the rest of your database-using code doesn't have to worry about such things - it just called the helper and when the helper returns, the database is exactly as it should be.

That's why the helper has an 'onCreate' method (which is used when the database doesn't already exist) and an 'onUpdate' method (which is used when the database already exists, but has a different version number).

Answer (score 2):

The data base is created only if it does not exist. That is the only time that the `onCreate` method is called. Once created, the data base will remain in existence until you explicitly delete it or until the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create your database it will be create the first time you use the `SQLiteOpenHelper` object and it will be permanent

Answer (score 1):

Please check by running application on real device. You may be using it on Emulator.

When you start application in emulator the database is created and when you close emulator the temporary environment created by emulator is destroyed thus you will not be able to get it back. Whether running on actual device may store database permanently on your device. So next time when you open your application, it will connect to existing database and you can do operations on it.

You have not provided information regarding whether you are using real device or emulator, please describe that.

Let me know if there is anything more -Thanks.